# Where should I ask a question about APIs?

Tags: support, site-recommendation

In which Stack Exchange site should I ask a question about which APIs to use for a certain problem, pricing, and the logistics (financial, and technical) of using them for my app?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[Software Recommendations](http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com) has some questions requesting for [APIs](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/api). You might be able to get help there, but be sure to read their [guidelines](https://softwarerecs.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/336/what-is-required-for-a-question-to-contain-enough-information) before posting. Without enough information, your question will be closed quickly.