# Asking questions about APIs negatively perceived

Tags: discussion

I have to ask, as I see in a [previous question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/339770/where-should-i-ask-a-question-about-apis) that [Software Recommendations](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/) is the appropriate place to ask questions about a specific library when we're talking about billing, changes, or anything that doesn't involve direct code, why is this the case? Shouldn't Stack Overflow be for coding/programming related questions that are well articulated and offer future readers an answer of substance? Or should Stack Overflow be *strictly* for debugging code directly?

Comment: I recommend to focus on the question and skip the part about downvotes for newbie questions.

Comment: That remark is just to highlight that I've found that votes don't always accurately represent quality.

Comment: Please try to reflect your question on https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic I.e. discuss why that help text does not cover your concern.

Comment: see... you're missing context. General questions about using or implementing apis would generally be on topic for Stack Overflow assuming they were well researched/written. The one you linked to instead is asking *which* api they should use, which is obviously a recommendation question and *not* on topic on Stack Overflow

Comment: Okay that's fair, so given the examples of billing, changes, and clarification on documentation, this WOULD belong in StackOverflow?

Comment: Stack Overflow wouldn't be the right place to ask about a particular business's billing strategies... i don't know that such a place exists on the network. That isn't a (programming) problem.

Comment: @yunnosch that help text does not help me because it still leaves APIs/libraries kind of broad unless they can be classified as "tools".

Comment: @KevinB so hypothetically I ask a question regarding confusion in billing documentation, and the particular provider has snail-mail support channels, would it be off-topic to ask "What does this API charge for 25k requests" if their documentation doesn't provide that information?

Comment: Correct. That would be off topic.

Comment: Is there anywhere that that could be asked and documented? Its a linear question/answer and if the library provider isn't documenting it clearly it should be out there for whoever else needs to find the answer.

Comment: What is meta meant to be for by the way? Is it meant for asking this kind of question or have I totally misunderstood?

Comment: It is @CodeSpent. If you wonder why you have downvotes: downvotes here don't cause rep changes, so they flow a bit more freely.

Comment: @CodeSpent Meta is for questions about Main and how to use it (and also the Stack Exchange network as a whole) so questions like this are 100% okay here. Do note that voting can sometimes be harsher (or much nicer, depending) here than on main- There's a much smaller user base, fewer posts so more people are likely to see one post, and voting is different on Meta. Check out [What's Meta?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/help/whats-meta) for more info.

Comment: Could some of those downvoting offer some insight as to why they are doing so? I'd like to eventually figure out how all of this works, but its pretty hard when you're all in the shadows just saying "Hey you're wrong, but we're not saying why".

Comment: Explaining individual votes is rarely productive. Downvotes could be because the voters felt the question was poorly researched, or they felt it wasnt  particularly useful, or they may have not liked your non-sequitur about _down-votes for newbies_, or (and this is particular for meta), they may disagree with the general premise of your question. This, as a general guideline, should be enough for almost any case. But if you read the comments above, you should be able to put together some of the reasons for some downvotes. Note that those commenting and those voting may not have been the same.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [We're not \[customer-support\] for (your favorite company)](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/356660/were-not-customer-support-for-your-favorite-company)

Comment: @gnat that's ...  a burninate request. Did you perhaps mean [Why we're not customer support for [your favorite company](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/255745/why-were-not-customer-support-for-your-favorite-company)?

Comment: If you are in doubt *Can I ask this question here?*, then ask on meta first. Also, there's [this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/252777/is-there-a-less-restrictive-stack-exchange-site-specially-suited-for-not-too-spe) that may help you.

Comment: That's good advice there, thanks.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

We can't answer questions about billing, changes or anything that doesn't involve direct code because that's not the scope of Stack Overflow.

Billing matters should be taken up with the company you're doing business with.  I don't know how deep your pockets are.

Changes to the API *might* be on-topic here, since we have had that happen before.  Although I'd strongly argue that if you're paying for support, you may want to ask them first.

Things that don't involve direct code aren't our expertise.  We're professional engineers, developers, architects, and we deal with direct code better than we deal with any of the other stuff.

Comment: So where would be a good place for developers to share information and knowledge with each other? If I have a question about a library, and the library's "company" offers no support, and I know others use this library, is there nowhere on StackExchange where you won't be demonized for saying "Hey, I want to do this with x, their documentation is unclear and no one can help me" and them respond with "Hey, I had this problem too, here's the details I found"?

Comment: Kinda depends on what the *actual* question is.  We're not a forum so asking a "can you help me" style question is sure to be met with some pitchforks.  Although, the conventional wisdom is simple; if the library isn't supported, it's best to not use it and to find another one.